# Create a 3D-Area from a dataframe using Python

Tags: python, dataframe, charts, visualization

I have a dataframe with the following behavior:

|  | 30 | 35 | 40 | 45 | 50 | 55 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -40 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| -39 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| -38 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 | 60 | 70 |
| -37 | 33 | 0.5 | 2 | 10 | 90 | 80 |
| - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| 85 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |

suppose the list [30,35,40,45,50,55] represents the force applied to a body and [-40,-39,...,85] some temperatures. the rest of the table represents some data resulted after some computation between force, temperature and something else.
I need to have an output such this:

[image]

this plot was created in excel using **3-D Area**.

Having this dataframe and imagine there are more than 5 values for the applied force how can I plot something like this using Python. I did some trials, but for the moment I am stuck

```
forces = df.columns.values
temperatures = df.index.values
data = df.to_numpy()


# Create meshgrid
F, T = np.meshgrid(forces, temperatures)

# Reshape data to match meshgrid
Z = data.reshape(F.shape)

# Plot 3D area
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(F, T, Z, cmap='viridis')
ax.set_xlabel('Force')
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature')
ax.set_zlabel('Data')
plt.show()
```

How can I proceed to have the same results as using 3D Area?

```
forces = df.columns.values
temperatures = df.index.values
data = df.to_numpy()


# Create meshgrid
F, T = np.meshgrid(forces, temperatures)

# Reshape data to match meshgrid
Z = data.reshape(F.shape)

# Plot 3D area
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(F, T, Z, cmap='viridis')
ax.set_xlabel('Force')
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature')
ax.set_zlabel('Data')
plt.show()
```